# How can I restore my sound card not listet in pacmd list-cards?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, pulseaudio, soundcard

I'm running

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

and my sound card is listed in

```
$ lspci -v
...
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 36
    Memory at f7ff8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
...
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at fbc7c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
...
```

and my sound was working until yesterday without any special configuration via the Intel sound card. Yesterday it stopped and I can't figure out the reason. Maybe it's some update or some configuration changes that happened unintentionally when playing around with docker, not doing anything with sound. I can exclude a hardware defect, since everything works unchanged under Windows.

The Intel sound card is not found in

```
$ pacmd list-cards
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xfbc7c000 irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0beb"
        device.product.name = "GF104 High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "GF104 High Definition Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

but in

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [MID            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel MID
                      HDA Intel MID at 0xf7ff8000 irq 36
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xfbc7c000 irq 17
```

and in

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: ALC889 Analog [ALC889 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 1: ALC889 Digital [ALC889 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`$ pavucontrol` only shows a `Dummy Output`

I already tried

1. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio  sudo alsa force-reload` from [Sound stops working on Ubuntu 20.10 after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294011/sound-stops-working-on-ubuntu-20-10-after-reboot)
2. `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` from ["Dummy Output" No sound in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914463/dummy-output-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04) (not tried the dis- reenable in the BIOS though)
3. `sudo killall pulseaudio rm -rf ~/.config/pulse pulseaudio -k` from [Sound card gone from pactl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943509/sound-card-gone-from-pactl)

I also found [LSPCI finds my sound card but alsa and pacmd don't](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064367/lspci-finds-my-sound-card-but-alsa-and-pacmd-dont) but there is no accepted answer so I didn't want to mess up anything additionally.

Any idea on how to fix this?

**UPDATE**:
I did a dist-upgrade to 20.10 to try to fix this, without any success.
But something changed:

```
$ pacmd list-cards
2 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 23
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xfbc7c000 irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0beb"
        device.product.name = "GF104 High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "GF104 High Definition Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 24
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel MID"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel MID at 0xf7ff8000 irq 36"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "3b56"
        device.product.name = "5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 65, available: no)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6500, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6565, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-21: Analog Surround 2.1 Output (priority 1300, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 2.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1365, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-40: Analog Surround 4.0 Output (priority 1200, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1265, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-41: Analog Surround 4.1 Output (priority 1300, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1365, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-50: Analog Surround 5.0 Output (priority 1200, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1265, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-51: Analog Surround 5.1 Output (priority 1300, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1365, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-71: Analog Surround 7.1 Output (priority 1200, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 7.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1265, available: no)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (priority 5500, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5565, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:analog-surround-51>
    ports:
        analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority 8500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority 8200, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-linein: Line In (priority 8100, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
```

But `pavucontrol` still only shows a Dummy Device. Just after the upgrade the Device appeared in the "Sound Settings" but didn't output anything and disappeared after changing a profile. After a couple of minutes and the reexecution of the commands above it's now showing the device but not playing any sound nor are there any speakers shown in the "test" dialog.

Update: I got too frustrated about it. So I created a backup and a installation script to setup my system from scratch without effort in the future. After the reinstall everything worked again. Sorry for not posting a solution for anyone who stumbles upon this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer can help some people. I had the same issue, where I couldn't find GPU output device under pulse. It turned out I installed NVIDIA server driver.

You can check this by typing `$nvidia-smi`
[image: NVIDIA DRIVER VERSION]